# Is there any way to declare that an inner class has the same generic type as the outer?

Tags: java, generics, inner-classes

Is there any way to reuse the generic parameters of an outer class by an inner class?

---

I have the following class

```
public class TaggedUnionBuilder<L,R>{
    private final Class<L> leftClass;
    private final Class<R> rightClass;

    public TaggedUnionBuilder( Class< L > leftClass, Class< R > rightClass ) {
        this.leftClass = leftClass;
        this.rightClass = rightClass;
    }

    TaggedUnion<L,R> left( L aLeft ){
        return new TaggedUnion<>( true, aLeft  );
    }

    TaggedUnion<L,R> right( R aRight ){
        return new TaggedUnion<>( false, aRight  );
    }


    public class TaggedUnion<L,R>{
        private final boolean isLeftClass;
        private final Object value;


        private TaggedUnion( boolean isLeftClass, Object value ) {
            this.isLeftClass = isLeftClass;
            this.value = value;
        }

        L left(){
            //vvv compiler error vvv
            return leftClass.cast( value );
            //^^^ compiler error ^^^
        }

        R right(){
            //vvv compiler error vvv
            return rightClass.cast( value );
            //^^^ compiler error ^^^
        }

        boolean isLeft(){
            return isLeftClass;
        }

        boolean isRight(){
            return !isLeftClass;
        }
    }

}
```

However, I have a get the errors:

> java: incompatible types: L cannot be converted to L
>
> java: incompatible types: R cannot be converted to R

in the `left()` and `right()` methods.

It seems like the declaration of `L` and `R` in `TaggedUnion` are shadowing the declaration in `TaggedUnionBuilder`. If I remove the generic parameter declaration for `TaggedUnion` I cannot return it as a generic type.

If I remove the generic parameters off of `TaggedUnion` I get the errors

> java: type TaggedUnionBuilder.TaggedUnion does not take parameters

Comment: Remove `<A,B>` from the `TaggedUnion` class. Since the nested class isn't static, the `<A,B>` type parameters of `TaggedUnionBuilder` applies to `TaggedUnion` too,

Comment: You don't need to declare type parameters in `TaggedUnion`. Just use `A` and `B`, what's the problem?

Comment: If you deploy the Builder pattern, you normally write the builder as inner class of the class, not the other way around. Aside from that, the inner class is generic, when the enclosing class is generic. You can already use the generic parameters of the outer class.

Comment: @Andreas then you cannot return `TaggedUnion` as generic from TaggedUnionBuilder's `left` & `right` methods. You get the error >java: type TaggedUnionBuilder.TaggedUnion does not take parameters

Comment: @lexicore because then consumers of the union won't know the possible types

Comment: @ArtB The parameters go on  `TaggedUnionBuilder`, not on `TaggedUnion`

Comment: @ArtB Well, you'll have to remove `<A, B>` and `<>` there as well.

Comment: @ArtB When you remove type parameter from `TaggedUnion`, remove them everywhere, including on the `left` method: `TaggedUnion left( A aA ){ return new TaggedUnion( true, aA  ); }`

Comment: @lexicore Yeah, sure, that makes it compile, but useless. The goal is to have a TaggedUnion with generic types.

Comment: With the solution proposed above, the returned type will be a `TaggedUnionBuilder<A,B>.TaggedUnion`, the generic is still ok with this

Comment: @ArtB well the whole class seems pretty useless because if you can cast one type into another, they stand in some kind of inheritance relationship...

Comment: Because `TaggedUnion` is non-static, the full name, as seen by caller, is `TaggedUnionBuilder<Foo,Bar>.TaggedUnion`. Perhaps you wanted `TaggedUnion` to be static with it's own `A` and `B`?

Comment: @ArtB `TaggedUnion` *is* generic. `left()` and `right()` return `TaggedUnionBuilder<A, B>.TaggedUnion`.

Comment: @lexicore Yeah, I didn't think about referencing it with the parent name, I just wanted to have `TaggedUnion<A,B>` because otherwise it's verbose, but yes, it works for the question as stated... just not ergonmic :-/

Comment: @lexicore Used your comment to create a new answer. If you want to copy and paste it to claim it as your own I'll accept it.

Comment: @Turing85 They are not expected to be related, you know which method is safe to call by checking the `isLeft()` method before calling `left()`

Comment: @ArtB from [the documentation of `Class#cast(Object o)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#cast-java.lang.Object-): "*Throws: ClassCastException - if the object is not null and is not assignable to the type T.*" In other words: if `A` and `B` are not related, you will get an `ClassCastException`.

Comment: @Turing85 yes, if you call `left()` without ensuring that `isLeft()` is `true` you will get a `ClassCastException`. That is why that code is there to catch that instead of silently failing because of erasure. If you didn't care about that you wouldn't need to pass in the `Class` objects at all.

Comment: How come you have some variable and you don't know whether it is a `String` or a `Date`?

Comment: @Turing85 A contrived example. A list of appointments with the date as a free text field. Some of them can be parsed into a real date "2018-04-11", and some that can't "after Jon's birthday". In that case we can parse it into a date, we can do additional logic, but otherwise we still need to track the data even if we cannot action it.

Comment: Wouldn't it be cleaner to have separate `Appointment` implementations for those cases? This way, you can define the "additional logic" behaviour in the right context.

Comment: @Turing85 if you would like model it as part of your domain then yes, but if you need it as a one off in a small method this is nicer. Same argument goes for Guava's Pair and Triple classes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have an inner class, the generic type are "propagated" into the inner class too.

```
public class Outer<A> {

    Inner in;

    Outer( A a ) {
        in = new Inner( a );
    }

    Inner get() {
        return in;
    }

    class Inner {
        A value;

         Inner( A value ) {
            this.value = value;
        }
    }

    public static void main( String[] args ) {
        String s = new Outer<>( "test" ).get().value;
        //And to declare an variable Inner
        Outer<String>.Inner i = new Outer<>( "test" ).get();
    }
}
```

Declaring an `Outer<String>` will then give a `Outer<String>.Inner`, the `value` will be a `String`.

If you declare an `Inner`, you need to use the full class name to specify the generic type, a bit more verbose but a correct solution.

Answer (score 2):

One work around it to make the inner class `TaggedUnion` a `static class` and pass in an instance of `TaggedUnionBuilder` explicitly. This would resolve the issue.

```
public class TaggedUnionBuilder<L,R>{
    private final Class<L> leftClass;
    private final Class<R> rightClass;

    public TaggedUnionBuilder( Class< L > leftClass, Class< R > rightClass ) {
        this.leftClass  = leftClass;
        this.rightClass = rightClass;
    }

    public TaggedUnion<L,R> left( L aLeft ){
        return new TaggedUnion<>( this, true, aLeft  );
    }

    public TaggedUnion<L,R> right( R aRight ){
        return new TaggedUnion<>( this, false, aRight  );
    }


    public static class TaggedUnion<L,R>{
        private final boolean isLeftClass;
        private final Object value;
        private final TaggedUnionBuilder<L,R> parent;


        private TaggedUnion( TaggedUnionBuilder<L,R> aParent, boolean isLeftClass, Object aValue ) {
            this.parent = aParent;
            this.isLeftClass = isLeftClass;
            this.value = aValue;
        }

        public L left(){
            return parent.leftClass.cast( value );
        }

        public R right(){
            return parent.rightClass.cast( value );
        }

        public boolean isLeft(){
            return isLeftClass;
        }

        public boolean isRight(){
            return !isLeftClass;
        }
    }

}
```

but effectively makes `TaggedUnion` a separate class (would just need to make accessors for the classes on `TaggedUnionBuilder`).

Comment: It is a workaround but change the context a bit, a nested class and a static nested class are two different thing... This can be confusing to find twice `L` and `R` but those can actually be different types in these classes.

Comment: Well it is safe because of the private constructor ensures they will always be the same, but yes, you are right.

Comment: Yes, I was editing to add that you used a safeguard that is MANDATORY to use safely that solution ;)

Answer (score 1):

The real answer to the question as stated (given by @lexicore in the comments) is to qualify the returned type using the parent name like such:

```
public class TaggedUnionBuilder<A,B>{
    private final Class<A> classA;
    private final Class<B> classB;

    public TaggedUnionBuilder( Class< A > classA, Class< B > classB ) {
        this.classA = classA;
        this.classB = classB;
    }

    public TaggedUnionBuilder<A,B>.TaggedUnion left( A aA ){
        return new TaggedUnion( true, aA  );
    }

    public TaggedUnionBuilder<A,B>.TaggedUnion right( B aB ){
        return new TaggedUnion( false, aB  );
    }


    public class TaggedUnion{
        private final boolean isClassA;
        private final Object value;

        private TaggedUnion( boolean isClassA, Object aValue ) {
            this.isClassA = isClassA;
            this.value = aValue;
        }

        A left(){
            return classA.cast( value );
        }

        B right(){
            return classB.cast( value );
        }

        boolean isA(){
            return isClassA;
        }

        boolean isB(){
            return !isClassA;
        }
    }

}
```

But this means you cannot refer to `TaggedUnion` genericly *without* including the containing class in the type (ie always `TaggedUnionBuilder<A,B>.TaggedUnion` instead of `TaggedUnion`) which is brutal ergonomically but answers the question as stated.

Answer (score 0):

**Preface**

Let me start by doubting the usefulness of a class like the one you showed. If one is able to cast one type into another, either at least one type is an interface or both types stand in an inheritance relationship. From my point of view, you can do all this with [`Class#isAssignableForm(Object obj)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#isAssignableFrom-java.lang.Class-), [`Class#isInstance(Object obj)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#isInstance-java.lang.Object-) and [`Class#cast(Object obj)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#cast-java.lang.Object-).

When deploying the [Builder Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern), one normally writes the builder as inner static class of the actual type. This facilitates readability (the important class is the POJO, not the builder). Furthermore, an inner (non-static) class always has an implicit reference to the instance of the surrounding class it was created from.

---

**Is there any way to reuse the generic parameters of an outer clas by an inner class?**

Yes there is. Let's look at some simplified version of your code.

```
public class TaggedUnionBuilder<A, B> {
    // ...
    public class TaggedUnion {
        // ...
    }
}
```

As we know, we instantiate inner classes by first instantiating an instance of the outer class and THEN calling `new <InnerClass>()` on this instance like so:

```
TaggedUnionBuilder<String, Object> builder = new TaggedUnionBuilder<String, Object>();
TaggedUnionBuilder<String, Object>.TaggedUnion union = builder.new TaggedUnion();
```

Writing this, one sees that the complete type of `union` is indeed `TaggedUnionBuilder<String, Object>.TaggedUnion`.

---

**What does this mean for the implementation?**

We can use generic parameters `A` and `B` already in `TaggedUnion`. Thus, we can refactor the code to:

```
public class TaggedUnionBuilder<A, B> {
    private final Class<A> classA;
    private final Class<B> classB;

    public TaggedUnionBuilder(Class<A> classA, Class<B> classB) {
        this.classA = classA;
        this.classB = classB;
    }

    TaggedUnion left(A a) {
        return new TaggedUnion(true, a);
    }

    TaggedUnion right(B b) {
        return new TaggedUnion(false, b);
    }

    public class TaggedUnion {
        private final boolean isClassA;
        private final Object  value;

        private TaggedUnion(boolean isClassA, Object value) {
            this.isClassA = isClassA;
            this.value = value;
        }

        A left() {
            return classA.cast(value);
        }

        B right() {
            return classB.cast(value);
        }

        boolean isA() {
            return isClassA;
        }

        boolean isB() {
            return !isClassA;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It is not an inheritance relationship. It is used for in my case Strings and Dates. If the type `TaggedUnion<String,Date>` you know that if `isLeft()` is `true` then `left()` will return a `String` and `right()` will produce `ClassCastException`, likewise when `isRight()` is `true` (ie `isLeft()` is `false`) `right()` returns a `Date` and `left()` a `ClassCastException`... and the whole thing get weird with `null`.